# Is the fraction of the irrational exponentiations of two coprime integers by a rational an irrational?

Tags: irrational-numbers, fractions, exponentiation, rational-numbers

Consider two strictly positive integer coprimes $n, m\in\mathbb{N^*}$ and a rational $r=\frac{p}{q}\in\mathbb{Q}$. Consider furthermore that the three number statifies the following condition:

- $x=n^r$ is an irrational number
- $y=m^r$ is an irrational number

Question: is $\frac{x}{y}$ an irrational (neither rational or integer)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Yet another use of the rational root theorem, $x/y = (n/m)^r$ solves $z^q - (n^p/m^p) =0$, now with leading coefficient $\neq 1$.

Comment: I edited the question (added "or an integer").